# Does anyone know why Google recommends Microdata over Microformats and RDFa?

Tags: microdata, microformats, rdfa

I have researched a lot about the mark-up formats Microdata, Microformats and RDFa. Google recommend Microdata over the other two mark-ups and I want to know why. Reading a ton of documents and studying these mark-ups leaves me more clueless than before I started reading. Does anyone know why Google recommend this type? Is it something to with HTML5?

[Here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) is a link to the site where I got the information from Google.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is simply because schema.org is Google's own initiative (they created it together with Microsoft and Yahoo). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema.org.

Comment: Cheers that seems perfectly reasonable, thanks for pointing this out for me!

Comment: Note that you can use the vocabularies from schema.org with RDFa, too.

Answer (score 6):

Because of the many (syntax) errors found in RFDa usage. One of the leaders of Schema.org talks about the reason they chose microdata:

> (...) the error rate (i.e., webmasters marking up their pages to
>   say X when the really meant to say Y) was about 3 times as much [with RFDa, red.] as it was
>   for other formats (which include microformats, sitemaps, Google shopping
>   feeds, etc.). (...) More than 40% of the errors had to
>   do with the confusion between rel and property.
>
> (...) We really don't want to get into whether there is a distinction between rel
>   and property at a theoretical level. We also understand that there are some
>   corner cases which lead the authors of RDFa to make this distinction. But
>   the bottom line remains that as long as the error rate in RDFa usage does
>   not go down dramatically, it is not a viable option for us. (...)

[Source](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2011Oct/0113.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another perspective:  http://manu.sporny.org/2012/microdata-cr/
Interesting how we all used to loath Microsoft for perverting standards.  Guess Google is now stepping into their shoes.